# WinForms WebBrowser with DocumentStream not showing PDF

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I have a .Net framework 4.0 win form and I want to show a popup with a PDF.

The first thing I've tried is to pass the URL to the a WebBrowser control and it works like a charm:

```cs
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Url = new Uri("http://www.somestuff.com/pdf");
browser.BringToFront();
browser.Show();
```

But then I realized that I must point to another URL which requires windows authentication in order to get the PDF, so I changed my code in order to (a) get the PDF properly and (b) load the PDF with DocumentStream instead of Url, like this:

```cs
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.somestuff.com/pdf");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential() {
    UserName = "user", Password = "pass", Domain = "domain"
};

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

browser.DocumentStream = response.GetResponseStream();

browser.BringToFront();
browser.Show();
```

But this gives me a white browser without anything.
If I try to open the PDF on a real browser and put the credentials to that URL it works, but like this it doesn't.

What do I need to do different or add in order to make this work?
If I have the stream I believe this should work right?

Comment: if I'm not mistaking the WebBrowser control is derived from IE so an ancient beast I think you should be using the WebView2 control (is a NuGet package). Perhaps that new view is able to show PDF, but not sure about the latter

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. That was exactly what I was trying to check but it only works with .Net framework 4.5+, I'm unable to upgrade framework on this project...

Comment: In that case: you cannot directly show a PDF - IE couldn't do that either, so the only option is to download the PDF as a file to the local system and start a process with that PDF location hoping the OS will sort it out for you.

Comment: You can use the Open Source [PdfiumViewer](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer), your .Net Framework version is supported. It provides a WinForms Control (PdfViewer), that can render PDF Documents (also print and save to file)

Comment: Note that you need two NuGet Packages: the main [PdifiumViewer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfiumViewer/) and the [Build Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfiumViewer.Native.x86_64.v8-xfa)